# Monitor Stops Working on Ubuntu Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberrypi, monitor

I have installed Ubuntu 21.10 on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. I try to connect it to my monitor, and it starts up find, and sometimes I'll even see the login screen, before I lose connection. The only things I have changed is `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d`. Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to Linux.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question... are you able to test with a different monitor and cable?

Comment: I have a different monitor I can test with. Also, the terminal works without the display turning off. (The ctrl+alt+f3 one)

Comment: It is 3840x2160 and 60hz.

Comment: NOTE: I think it fixed when I plugged it into HDMI 1 instead...